# decode numbers in an array and compare to different array

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays, one containing numbers and another one containing encoded numbers.

I need to match the encoded numbers to the normal numbers to find a match.  The trick is that I need to decode the numbers to find a match.

```
let encoded = ['310254@3543129', '03254@03715P5'];
let numbers = ['3102540003543129', '0325400003715445', ...]
```

I have tried using a for loop with recursion for when there are multiple special characters in the string, but I am not getting the results correctly.

```
for (let i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++) {
for (let j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {

function removeSpecialChars(referenceNumber) {
    if(!/^\d*$/.test(referenceNumber)){
        for (let x = 0, invalidChar = ''; invalidChar = referenceNumber.charAt(x); x++) {
            let newString = '';
            // which char is invalid
            if (!/^\d*$/.test(invalidChar)) {
                for(let y = 0; i < numbers[j].split('').length; y++){
                    if(numbers[j].split('')[x] === numbers[j].split('')[x + y]){
                        newString += numbers[j].split('')[x];
                    } else break;
                 }
            return removeSpecialChars(referenceNumber.replace(invalidChar, newString));
            }
        }
    }

    return referenceNumber;
} // end function

if (removeSpecialChars(encrypted[i]) === numbers[j]) {
    count++;
}

}
}
```

I am not sure if I am approaching this in the wrong way entirely or if I am just missing something.

Here is a fiddle to reproduce my results.
https://jsfiddle.net/6ezuwhdb/1/

Comment: do you like to replace `@` with three zeroes? btw, have you read any of the comments of fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that there are at least 2 rules at play here (I haven't looked at the fiddle in any detail but what there is here can be easily extended):

1. `000` is encoded with a `@`, and
2. `44` is encoded with a `P`

I would first get a complete list of these rules together and then use regular expressions to replace all instances of the special characters with their numeric equivalents.

The regular expressions use the `g` modifier so that all instances of the encoded value get replaced within the string.

```js
const encoded = ['310254@3543129', '03254@03715P5'];

const decoded = encoded.map(en => {
  // replace the special characters using multiple regular expressions
  let result = en;
  // swap all @'s for 
  result = result.replace(/@/g, '000');
  // swap all P's for 44
  result = result.replace(/P/g, '44');
  // add more rules here ...

  return result;
});

console.log('Decoded numbers: ', decoded);
```

To then check whether the normal numbers can be found within the decoded set of numbers is fairly straight forward.

```js
// From previous step ;o)
const decoded = [
  "3102540003543129",
  "0325400003715445"
];

const numbers = ['3102540003543129', '0325400003715445'];
const matchedNumbers = numbers.filter(number => {
  return decoded.indexOf(number) >= 0;
});

console.log(matchedNumbers);
```

Comment: I thought of this too.  I just don't want to make the assumption that the encoding chars will always be the same

Comment: Unless you specifically know that they are not always going to be the same, stick with the hard-coded version until the requirement changes, then refactor (have different decoding functions.) Don't get bogged down trying to come up with an overly complicated, one size fits all, solution for something that may never happen.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks.